# Wordpress multisite - getting data from wp_sitemeta

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-theming, multisite

I have a multisite network with around 30 sites on it.

In the `wp_sitemeta` table, there are some options the previous dev had set (one of which is 'template_color').

So in the `wp_sitemeta` table, there is a `site_id` with a `meta_key` of 'template_color', and a `meta_value` of the hex value of the color for each theme.

I've written the following:

```
foreach ( $sites as $site ) {
        switch_to_blog( $site->blog_id );
        //do things
        $value = get_site_option( 'template_color', 'not available' );
        echo $value;
        restore_current_blog();

}
```

But `$value` just shows 'not available' for each site.

Am I doing something incorrectly?

Comment: I'd think Francesco answer is the right approach... would be nice to know where are you running this code and how you're getting `$sites` value

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Did you try get_option() in place of get_site_option()?

get_site_option() on multisite should return always network-wide settings ;)

Instead, get_option() should return site-specific ones.

Let me know!

Comment: if I switch to `$value = get_option( 'header_hex', 'not available');` it still doesn't display anything. But I can look at the DB and I see that `header_hex` is set for each site.

Comment: I'm on mobile, so just guessing, but OP is mentioning a network table, no?

Comment: Can you upload a snapshot of your table?

Comment: So, I thought it was a multisite network - what I had overlooked (forgotten) is that it was multi-network and multi-site. I was able to use something similar to this but at the network level, to exact what I needed.